# Window.SizeToContent issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

My app has a `Window` with a `TextBox` in it. My `Window`'s `SizeToContent` is set to `WidthAndHeight`. I show this window from a background thread using `Dispatcher.Invoke()`. The problem is that the Window doesn't size to its contents when it first appears. As soon as I change text of the `TextBox`, the `Window` shrinks to correct size.

I have tried calling the following too in `Dispatcher.Invoke()`:

1. `Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => { }));`
2. `WindowObject.InvalidateVisual();`
3. `WindowObject.UpdateLayout();`

but it doesn't affect initial window size. What do I need to do?

**UPDATE**: I also confirmed that `Window` shrinks to correct size if I assign a value to `TextBox`'s `Text` property programmatically. Adding the following 3 lines after calling `WindowObject.Show()` in `Dispatcher`-invoked function sets it to correct size:

```
var Old = WindowObject.TXT.Text;
WindowObject.TXT.SetCurrentValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "");
WindowObjectTXT.SetCurrentValue(TextBox.TextProperty, Old);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and by using either *Show* or *ShowDialog* method of Window to display the Window with the Textbox you want to open up with its adjusted intiial windows size, I could display this window with the correct size.

I added a button with the following click handler to display the window:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
        {
            var pWnd = new PopWindow();
            pWnd.ShowDialog();
            pWnd.InvalidateVisual();
            pWnd.UpdateLayout();

        }));
 }
```

[image: Simple test]